# отсортировать массив $arResult по массиву с нужными ID

Tags: php, битрикс

в компоненте catalog.section  в файле result_modifier.php хочу отсортировать массив $arResult по массиву со значениями ID , который приходит из компонента   bitrix:search.page.
массив $arResult  имеет ключ ['ID'] и унего получаются такие значения:

```
$arResult[0]['ID']=>int(4509044)
$arResult[2]['ID']=>int(4509045)
$arResult[3]['ID']=>int(4504824)
$arResult[4]['ID']=>int(4509046)
```

массив по которому сортировать $GLOBALS['Filter'] имеет вид

```
[0]=>int(4504824)
[1]=>int(4509046)
[2]=>int(4509044)
[3]=>int(4509045)
```

Не пойму как это сделать, есть мысли в сторону usort()

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
$newArResult = array();
foreach ($arResult as $value) {
    $newArResult[$value['ID']] = $value;
}

$arResult = array();
foreach ($GLOBALS['Filter'] as $idFromFilter) {
    if(!empty($newArResult[$idFromFilter])){
        $arResult[ $idFromFilter ] = $newArResult[$idFromFilter];
    }
}
unset($newArResult);
```